# Add a URL image to a cell where the URL is based on input in another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am moving over a worksheet from GoogleDocs that has to be in Excel now.

It is a barcode generator sheet.

The image cell in GoogleDocs has the formula is

```
=image("www.somebarcodesite.com/image.php?code=" & A2 & "&style=197&type=C128B&width=300&height=50&xres=1&font=3", 3)
```

I've downloaded as Excel but that has not helped (I think due to text concatenation) and additional rows may be need to be added so it's not enough to embed the image once when downloading.

I've seen VB solutions to put an image in a cell, but I'm not sure it would allow the users to add new rows to the worksheet.

Does anyone know where I should start on finding a scalable way to show the image generated at a url, where the url is generated dynamically based on the input of other cells?